# sklearn cosine_distances between two strings varies depending on size of total data set?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, cosine-similarity, dbscan

I am trying to cluster bunch of strings using DBSCAN, with cosine_distances as the metric after doing TfidfVectorizer transform. Say I have two strings. The cosine_distance between them (computed using sklearn.metrics.pairwise.cosine_distance) when it's just those two strings is different than the distance between them when they are part of a larger data set (with many other strings).

Why does this happen and how can I ensure that the distance between any two strings is same regardless of the size of dataset they are part of?

That way, my DBSCAN can do clustering reliably!

EDIT: Adding example code as requested:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_distances

X = [
    'this is a string',
    'this was a string'
    ]

Y = [
    'this could be a string',
    'this may be a string'
    ]

Z = [
    'this is a string',
    'this was a string',
    'this could be a string',
    'this may be a string'
    ]

for d in [X, Y, Z]:
    tv = TfidfVectorizer()
    print(cosine_distances(tv.fit_transform(d)))
```

Outputs:

```
[[ 0.          0.49689739]
 [ 0.49689739  0.        ]]

[[ 0.          0.39702518]
 [ 0.39702518  0.        ]]

[[ 0.          0.64740127  0.70225689  0.70225689]
 [ 0.64740127  0.          0.70225689  0.70225689]
 [ 0.70225689  0.70225689  0.          0.46163155]
 [ 0.70225689  0.70225689  0.46163155  0.        ]]
```

As you can see here, the distance between `this is a string` and `this was a string` is `0.497` in dataset `X`, but it is `0.647` in dataset `Z`. Same for strings `this could be a string` and `this may be a string` in datasets `Y` and `Z`

In the above example, if I chose max distance (eps) parameter of DBSCAN to be 0.6, then in dataset X, both strings will be put in the same cluster, but in dataset Z, they will be put in different clusters.

Comment: please add an example / code to make your goal more clear

Answer (score 0):

Cosine similarity is suitable for **long documents**.

Short strings don't have enough words.

That the distance changes is due to the IDF part of TFIDF. You opted for a inverse document frequency weighting, so if the document frequency changes, distances change.

Comment: aw snap.. that's exactly right! I don't know why that did not occur to me. In that case, what is the right way to handle my requirement? What should I be using?

Comment: I don't know. It depends on your data, and the task that you need to solve. Your data probably isn't `this is a string`.

Comment: I would probably need to use CountVectorizer instead of TfIdf to make the distances immune to document frequency. Will think about it. Thanks.